# How to merge routes from different modules?

Tags: angular

`app.module.ts`

```
...
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RecipesModule
  ],
...
```

`app-routing.module.ts`

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/recipes', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent},
  {path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent},
  {path: 'not-found', component: NoSuchPageComponent, data: {message: 'Not Found!'}},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now the `recipes.module.ts`

```
...
imports: [
    RouterModule,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RecipesRoutingModule
  ]
...
```

and `recipes-routing.module.ts`

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'recipes', component: RecipesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children:
      [
        {path: '', component: RecipeStartComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'new', component: RecipeEditComponent},
        {path: ':id', component: RecipeDetailComponent, resolve: [RecipesResolverService]},
        {path: ':id/edit', component: RecipeEditComponent, resolve: [RecipesResolverService]}
      ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RecipesRoutingModule { }
```

How to merge `recipes-routing.module.ts` and `app-routing.module.ts` so that I can use routes from the `recipes-routing.module.ts`?

Comment: Why do you want to merge? what is that you want to achieve?

Comment: I need working routes like <host>/recipes, <host>/recipes/3/edit which are written in recipes-routing.module.ts, not in app-routing.module.ts
For now, <host>/recipes does not work.
I don't know how to import the Recipes module correctly into AppModule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lazyLoading

angular 8 syntax

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/recipes', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent},
  {path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent},
  {path: 'recipes', loadChildren: () => import('./recipes/recipes.module').then((m) => m.RecipesModule),
  {path: 'not-found', component: NoSuchPageComponent, data: {message: 'Not Found!'}},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found'}
];
```

the only caviat is based on how you designed your routes, for example new will be

`http://localhost/recipes/recipes/new`

if you want to solve this as well you need to change here (needs to be tested)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: RecipesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children:
      [
        {path: '', component: RecipeStartComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'new', component: RecipeEditComponent},
        {path: ':id', component: RecipeDetailComponent, resolve: [RecipesResolverService]},
        {path: ':id/edit', component: RecipeEditComponent, resolve: [RecipesResolverService]}
      ]
  }
];
```

also you can add `authGaurd` in the app-routing not in the module

Comment: How to merge two route tables so that `http://localhost/recipes/new` works?

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load angular modules take this example from scratch also look at this example code on stackblitz,

**App routing module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then import AppRoutingModule in your app.module.ts

**customers-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CustomerListComponent } from './customer-list/customer-list.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CustomerListComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CustomersRoutingModule { }
```

Look at the working example [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwl3ea?file=src/app/customers/customers-routing.module.ts) on stackblitz